# Can I change the Key of a Dictionary with the value of another Dictionary that has the same Key in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

In a nutshell, I want to replace the Key from a Dictionary with the value of another Dictionary that has the same Key as the first dict.

[image]

The output I'm expecting is the following:

`{'Sneakers-Viewed Product-(not set)' : 2}`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer is yes. Just insert the value with the new key and remove the old key. I'm not sure which difficulty you were facing.

Comment: You wouldn't be REPLACING the key.  You would be adding a new key/value pair. You could then delete the old one.  `dicta[dicb[0]] = dicta[0]` / `del dicta[0]`.

Comment: Also, [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You could have just copy-pasted those two dictionaries and formatted as code - just like you did with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this in one step:

```
dictionary[new_key] = dictionary.pop(old_key)
```